# Google Calendar API and shared hosting issue

Tags: c#-4.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to use a public Google calendar in a webpage that will need editing functionalities.
To that effect, I created the calendar and made it public. I then created a Google service account and the related client id.
I also enabled the Calendar API and added the v3 dlls to the project.
I downloaded the p12 certificate and that's when the problems start.

The call to Google goes with a X509 cert but the way the .NET framework is built is that it uses a user temp folder.
Since it's a shared host for the web server (GoDaddy), I cannot have the app pool identity modified.
As a result, I'm getting this error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

when calling:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(GoogleOAuth2CertificatePath,
                "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

that cerificate var is then to be used in the google call:

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(GoogleOAuth2EmailAddress)
                {
                    User = GoogleAccount,
                    Scopes = new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
                }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

... but I never get that far.

Question: is there a way to make the call differently, i.e. not to use a X509 certificate but JSON instead?
Or can I get the x509 function to use a general temp location rather than a user location to which I have no access to since I can't change the identity in the app pool?

Since I'm completely stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Surely using JSON you'll have the same problem - the issue is "I can't load a file" rather than being Google or X509-specific. You could potentially embed the certificate into an assembly and use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to load the data...

Comment: Agreed where did you put GoogleOAuth2CertificatePath?

Comment: the .p12 file is in the App_Data/MyGoogleStorage folder.

Comment: The .p12 file is in the App_Data/MyGoogleStorage folder.
I can download the file when typing the address directly so it's not a path or credentials issue.
I also agree that the issue is not with Google itself as I get stuck before the call when the x509 certificate gets actually created.
@Jon Skeet: I like your idea...would you have a code example please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can download the file when typing the address directly"? It shouldn't be exposed by your web app...

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I moved the MyGoogleStorage folder to the root and then downloaded the file and it worked. So the absolute path is correct. I then did the tests from that folder and it failed. Since that was cleared out, I moved the google folder back into App_Data where it's supposed to be from my understanding

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not with you at all. That sounds like a totally different code path... and you really, really need to make sure your certificate isn't public.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option which avoids needing to worry about file locations is to embed the certificate within your assembly. In Visual Studio, right-click on the file and show its properties. Under Build Action, pick "Embedded resource".

You should then be able to load the data with something like this:

```
// In a helper class somewhere...
private static byte[] LoadResourceContent(Type type, string resourceName)
{
    string fullName = type.Namespace + "." + resourceName;
    using (var stream = type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fullName)
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(output);
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
byte[] data = ResourceHelper.LoadResourceContent(typeof(MyType), "Certificate.p12");
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(data, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Here `MyType` is some type which is in the same folder as your resource.

Note that there are lots of different "web" project types in .NET... depending on the *exact* project type you're using, you may need to tweak this.

Comment: this is a web page project so I don't have the option to embed the file, or do I ? The only property I have in VS2012 is the file name and the local path

Comment: @Nick: It wasn't clear what kind of project you were using from your description. You could potentially put it into a separate class library... or upgrade to use a more fully-featured kind of web project...

Comment: the site is a .net 4.5 web application

Comment: @Nick: Right, if it's a web application then you should be able to add a resource with no problem. (And if you're using VS2012, that's C# 5 rather than C# 4, right?)

Comment: @Nick: I've just tried it - admittedly in VS2015 - creating a new WebForms application, and adding a file... I was able to set the build action fine.

Comment: It might sounds dum but I created the App_GlobalResources folder and put a copy of the .p12 file there. I can create the class with the first part of the code, right? And mytype would be something like System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources")?

Comment: @Nick: No, with my suggestion you wouldn't end up with a separate file on disk *at all* when the app is deployed. No `MapPath` or anything like that. I'm afraid I don't know much about web applications and where the appropriate place to put non-code, non-served content is - it may well be that there's a better solution to this than using an embedded resource, but I thought *a* solution would be better than nothing. You'd put the resource in the same folder as your code, and set it to be an embedded resource, and use any type within that same namespace to get at it.

Comment: for desktop adds, I'm used to the embedded resources to run external apps within my code for instance. I've never used embedded resources in a web app before which is why I may sound a bit lost. I do appreciate the effort and will look into the stream